# How to create a signal that delays the underlying signal and clears immediately

Tags: typescript, solid-js

I want to make a signal that sets itself to underlying signal or a memo after a certain delay, and clears immediately if the underlying signal is cleared. The following code demonstrates what I want.

```
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import { For, createSignal, createEffect } from "solid-js";

function Counter() {
   const [s, setS] = createSignal(undefined)
   const [delayedS, delayedSetS] = createSignal(undefined)


   setTimeout(() => {
     setS(10)
   }, 1000)

   setTimeout(() => {
     setS(undefined)
   }, 3000)

   createEffect(() => {
      let res = s()
      if (res !== undefined) {
         setTimeout(() => delayedSetS(res), 1000)
      } else {
         delayedSetS(undefined)
      }
   })

  return (<>
    <span> S {s()} </span>
    <span> Delayed S {delayedS()}</span>
    </>)
}

render(() => <Counter />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

This works, though Is this a correct approach. I am not sure if createDeferred provides this functionality, though I don't want to use that, since it uses a scheduler I am not sure what it does.

Comment: https://playground.solidjs.com/?hash=-197290838&version=1.3.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt was totally valid.

The [`createDeferred`](https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest/api#createdeferred), although it seams like it has a similar usecase, it wouldn't work here as intended, because:

1. The timeout passed to `createDeferred` is not an exact amount of time that it will wait before causing updates – it is a maximum timeout to wait before browser becomes idle.
2. The timeout would happen before both updating the signal to `undefined` and other values.

```js
const delayedS = createDeferred(s)
```

A preferable primitive for setting signals is [`createComputed`](https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest/api#createcomputed). It is a pure computation – similar to `createMemo` – meaning that it will run immediately before effects. In simple examples there is usually no difference to use of effect, but using an effect for setting signals could potentially cause more updates than necessary.

```js
  createComputed(
    on(s, (v) => {
      if (v) setTimeout(() => setDelayedS(v), 1000);
      else setDelayedS();
    })
  );
```

Additionally clearing the timeout on the set to `undefined` that happens without a delay, could eliminate some timing glitches.

```js
  let timeoutId = 0;
  createComputed(
    on(s, (v) => {
      if (v) timeoutId = setTimeout(() => setDelayedS(v), 1000);
      else {
        setDelayedS();
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      }
    })
  );
  onCleanup(() => clearTimeout(timeoutId));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`@solid-primitives/scheduled`](https://primitives.solidjs.community/package/scheduled) package which has some delayed reactive functionality.

```
import {createMemo, createSignal} from 'solid-js';
import {createScheduled, throttle} from '@solid-primitives/scheduled';

const [count, setCount] = createSignal(0);
const scheduled = createScheduled(callback => throttle(callback, 1000)); // 1000 ms delay

const debouncedCount = createMemo(
  (previousCount) => scheduled() ? count() : previousCount,
  0
);

createEffect(() => {
  // This message gets printed at most once every second because debouncedCount()
  // is a dependency, regardless of how many times setCount is called.
  console.log(debouncedCount());
});
```

Here, if one were to call `setCount` repeatedly, `debouncedCount` will only update every second. There are other scheduling options such as `debounce`, and modifiers such as `leading`.

The page above also has a [demo](https://primitives.solidjs.community/playground/scheduled) that demonstrates the differences between the different scheduling options.